# Low poly candle holder

Tags: modeling

I am seeing a lot of low poly candle holders on thingiverse for printing but would like to make my own. I haven't seen many tutorials. Can someone point me in the right direction to make something like this http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:18672

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Screw Modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/screw.html)

Just add the modifier to the choosen cross-section shape (an exagon for example).

With the options provided you should be able to easily control many aspect of the shape such as the overall height, the number of steps and the number of turns.

[image]

Then you could stack a **Triangulate** modifier for a better control upon the way non-planar faces are splitted.

[image]

Comment: This worked for me, but then I couldn't figure out how I got to your point.  When I create a cylinder and then add the screw modifier I end up with a ton of vertical lines which distort how I see the picture.  I can go in afterwards and remove them but then I end up with two separate objects.  I'm not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Maybe that's because you should not start from a "cylinder", but from a cross section figure, which I intend as bidimensional (a triangle, a square, a pentagon, an exagon...). Try to add a "circle" object instead and set the number of vertices to 6.

Answer (score 3):

Add a *Circle* with 6 vertices and extrude it (<kbd>E</kbd>). Subdivide it adding *edge loops* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>). Snap the cursor to the top edge loop (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>-->*Cursor to Selected*). Enable the *proportional editing*, increase the editing ring with <kbd>Mouse Scroll</kbd> and rotate (<kbd>R</kbd>) the top edge loop as pictured below.
[image]

Add the ***Solidify Modifier*** and play with its *Thickness* value.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Start by adding a cylinder and adjust the vertices count to 6 in the *operator panel*

[image]

Next, add a *simple deform* modifier and set it to *twist*. Adjust the angle as desired.

[image]

Add some loop cuts with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (I added 5),  and delete the top face in *edit mode*. Add a solidify modifier as well if desired and adjust the thickness as needed.

Following these steps, you should be able to achieve this kind of result:

[image]